# Fatest way to check if an item exist in a collection?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, performance, optimization, find

I have some concerns about a performance issue. I have a cron which runs every minutes, and updates a collection.

Every minute 10,000 new transactions are fetched from an external api. Some of these transaction records are already in my db.

```
for (transaction in transactions) {
    if (Transaction.findOne(_id: transactionId, { _id: 1}))
        console.log("Already in db");
    else
        Transaction.insert(transaction)
```

To speed this up, I loaded the full collection into memory, and only inserted at the end of my script.

```
const toInsert = [];

const transactions = await Transaction.find().select(_id);
// I transform array of transactions to an object of transaction where key is _id, thus i can avoid using a find at every iteration
const transactionsObject = transactions.reduce((obj, transaction) => {
     obj[transaction.id] = true;
     return obj;
   }, {})

for (transaction in transactions) {
    if (transactionsObject[transactionId])
        console.log("Already in db");
    else {
        toInsert.push(transaction);
        transactionsObject[transaction._id] = true;
}

Transaction.insertMany(toInsert);
```

With this version of my script, the script is very fast, but I have some concern about scalability, because I will need a lot of memory, and if I need to thread this, I will need to share everything between threads.

How would you optimize the script ?

Comment: By transactions, you mean "monetary transactions" and not ACID transactions, right? (That's what it looks like -- I just thought I'd clarify)

Comment: I meant monetary transactions yes

Comment: Where does the "collection" live (before you "load it into memory")?

Answer (score 0):

It might make sense to let mongo calculate which documents it's missing. One optimization would be to only find the ids of the transactions that you care about:

```js
const transactionIds = await Transaction.find({_id: {$in: listOfIds}}).select(_id);
```

An even faster alternative would be to create a unique index on your id (the default _id field already has a unique index) and then try and insert all of the documents with `{ordered: false}`. Some inserts will fail, but letting mongo make that calculation will be faster.

> With ordered [set] to false, the insert operation [will] continue with any remaining documents.
>   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/

```js
> db.test.insertMany([{_id: 1}], { ordered: false })
{ "acknowledged" : true, "insertedIds" : [ 1 ] }
> db.test.insertMany([{_id: 1}, {_id: 2}], { ordered: false })
2019-07-03T16:25:54.402+0000 E QUERY    [js] BulkWriteError: write error at item 0 in bulk operation :
BulkWriteError({
    "writeErrors" : [
        {
            "index" : 0,
            "code" : 11000,
            "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: _id_ dup key: { : 1.0 }",
            "op" : {
                "_id" : 1
            }
        }
    ],
    "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
    "nInserted" : 1,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "nRemoved" : 0,
    "upserted" : [ ]
})
```